How to put the same character in the beginning of all rows using regex?
I have a list of 10 digit numbers in a txt file.
I want to put the same character in the beginning of all rows using regex, without changing the numbers.
I also want to put the character at the end of all rows
For example a quote character '
Set of numbers as sample:
7101756638
7101756639
7107429322
7107429323
7108270737
7109747487

When I do this:

Search for: \d{10,10}
Replace with: '\d{10,10}'

I get this:
'd{10,10}'
'd{10,10}'
'd{10,10}'
'd{10,10}'
'd{10,10}'
'd{10,10}'


Did it work? ^([0-9]{10})$ replace it with '$1? If they are not in the same line, find ([0-9]{10}) and replace it with '$1?


You can use (?=^[0-9]{10}$) and replace it with '.
You can also use ^([0-9]{10})$ and then replace it with '$1.

Notes:

^: start anchor.
([0-9]{10}): capture group 1, including 10 digits.
$: end anchor.
(?=): positive lookahead.



Ctrl+H
Find what: ^\d+$
Replace with: '$0'
TICK Wrap around
SELECT Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:
^           # beginning of line
\d+         # 1 or more digit. you can use \d{10} if there is 10 digits or .+ to match any character
$           # end of line

Replacement:
'$0'        # the whole match surounded with single quotes

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):

